# A way to have Azure Insights log request payloads for the entry method (if not all methods) when a error occurs?

Tags: c#, azure, exception

So I've been trying to figure out ways to log a payload whenever an error is throw in multiple APIs.  But the problem is that I'm working with a large amount of end points and to manually log each one and write a try catch seems nightmarish at best.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a middleware to intercept requests before they hit your controller/action API with a global try { //AI Log request info } catch { //AI Log error }

Providing .NET 4.5 Owin middleware as example:

```
    public class LogGlobalErrorMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
    {
        private readonly OwinMiddleware _Next;
        private readonly ILog _logger;


        /// <summary>
        /// Ctror
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="next"></param> 
        /// <param name="healthCheck"></param>
        public LogGlobalErrorMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next, ILog logger) : base(next)
        {
            this._Next = next;
            this._logger = logger;
        }

        public async override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
        {
            await LogGlobalError(context);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Middleware logic to log global errors in our microservice
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private async Task LogGlobalError(IOwinContext context)
        {

            try
            {
                //Moving through pipeline
                await Next.Invoke(context);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error(ex, "An unhandled exception happened! ");
            }

        }


    }
```